Are questions about preventing LLM hallucinations on topic?
I've seen a few questions on this topic and I'd like the community's opinion.
Here's my analysis of a recent question that asks about LLM hallucinations interfering with their program behavior:

The C# code is not relevant The C# code in the post only serves to make an HTTP call, read the response, and execute the database query. This can be done in any language. As the question is about the HTTP response (the LLM result), anything that happens afterwards isn't important. The only important part is the string that is sent to the LLM.
If, however, the OP could prove that the they were getting different results using the C# library versus other languages, then it would be a question about the C# LLM library.

Because the C# code is not relevant, the question boils down to "what message do I give this LLM to get the output I expect?" This is Prompt Engineering, and I personally do not believe it is programming.

With most LLMs, the most the community can do is guess at what prompt will produce the right output. LLMs, by design, give unpredictable outputs. There is no guarantee that the same input a week later will produce the same output.

This isn't a programming question, it's a question about using some third party's service.

LLMs aren't primarily used by programmers.
If the third party service isn't behaving correctly, that feedback should be directed to the third party. The community can't fix the hosted LLM behavior.


While it doesn't have any effect on Stack Overflow's policies, Artificial Intelligence SE does forbid specific implementation questions, and GenAI has the Prompt Design tag.


Is this analysis right, wrong, a mix?

In fairness, OP in that question is using Ollama locally, it's not exactly a third party service.

Yes, but asking about asking such questions is not on topic. Haha. (kidding, of course). ;-)

Here's another similar question. If they narrow it down to "how can I prevent it using prompt engineering or adjustments to the API call parameters?", is that on topic?

@ggorlen i'd consider it on topic if it were asking how to detect and correct hallucinations in a given specific context as opposed to engineering a prompt to avoid them.

Blimey, using GenAI to write SQL statements is terrifying!

We have a whole site dedicated to prompt engineering, however that doesn't necessarily mean prompt engineering is off topic.
I would argue we treat prompt engineering the same way we do, say, server administration; If the problem is programmatic in nature, it's on topic. If it isn't, it's off topic.
If the given question does effectively boil down to what model to use or how to alter the prompt to get a specific response, that isn't programmatic in nature.

Do you have any examples of what might be on topic here? I don’t disagree but am having trouble coming up with examples myself that wouldn’t fall into the camp of AI research.

@bob Maybe writing code to guess at prompt responses and heuristically learn from them to improve your chances of getting the desired outcome, perhaps necessarily assuming a known good response rather than a dynamic response?

I just can't agree with this, you're trying to slice something up hypothetically in a way that doesn't exist. The message has to be extremely simple,  PROMPT ENGINEERING IS OFF TOPIC - case closed.

My tentative reaction here is "in a programmatic context (as described in Kevin B's answer to this question) it's on-topic, but hopelessly overbroad."
Preventing AI hallucinations is an unsolved research problem.  Stack Overflow is not really suited to that sort of thing; in general, answers on Stack Overflow can be verifiably correct (even if suboptimal), which is not going to be possible for something like this.  Inevitably, you're going to get stuff that half works, at best.

Hmm, would Google Search query engineering equally as on-topic, then? I don't see any difference between trying to filter a query to produce good search results versus trying to filter a query to produce good genAI responses. Neither seem (to me) to be about programming in the slightest.

@TylerH Yeah, good point; I phrased that badly.  I was thinking of this specific question, which was in a programmatic context...edited to reference Kevin B's answer.  If you think it (or, say, improving results of a program that queries Google Search programmatically) is just unconditionally off-topic, consider posting an answer to that effect.  Though ultimately, the distinction between "always off-topic" and "always closeable for some non-topicality-related reason" may be a distinction without a difference.

Yea, i can't really answer to this specific question as it is, i was more responding based on what gunr described it as. If it's more programming involved than they're describing it to be, then yea that falls within what would be on topic. but i'm unfamiliar with the language used.

Kind of reminds me of the good old days where if you would visit a game development forum or related site every day there would be a post that said "I want to create the next World of Warcraft. How do I do that?". Yeah well... first you have to invent new technology and design a game around it. I finally have a name for it that covers the bases. "Hopelessly overbroad".

I'll express this viewpoint as an answer so that those who want can upvote it,
I cannot see why we're making this complicated. Rules have to be dead simple to keep a site like this functioning.
PROMPT ENGINEERING IS OFF TOPIC - case closed. Why are we wildly over-complicating this?
There is a whole site for prompt engineering.
It's a commonplace that on, say, English, spelling questions are instantly migrated to English-Learning. There is never any whack debate about obscure corner cases.  Delete, migrate, end of story.

I mean, it is simple. if it's prompt engineering, it's off topic. if it's programming that happens to in one way or another involve prompt engineering, but prompt engineering isnt' the point, it's on topic. I don't understand the confusion. A programming problem simply being adjacent to prompt engineering shouldn't make it off topic.
